# Android bitwise xor error in OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, bit-manipulation, xor, bitwise-xor

I've tried bitwise xor on android but I get the following error:

```
04-11 00:25:47.404: E/cv::error()(7370): OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in void cv::binary_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, void (* const*)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, cv::Size, void*), bool), file /home/reports/ci/slave/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1021
```

Here is my code:

```
Mat temp1 = mRgba.submat(roi); 
Mat temp2 = Mat.zeros(temp1.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);    
Core.bitwise_xor(temp1, temp2, temp1);
```

I've also tried to instantiate temp1 and temp2 the following way:

```
Mat temp1 = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1); 
Mat temp2 = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

But still the same error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't mention the type of `mRgba`, but from the name I assume it is RGBA, or `CV_8UC4`. This means that `temp1` will be of the same type as `mRgba`. As the error states, both matrices must be of the same size and type. That means that either `temp2` must be declared as type `CV_8UC4` or you must first convert `mRgba` to `CV_8UC1`, perhaps via converting to greyscale. I'm not familiar with the Java interface, but the equivalent C++ call would be:

```
cv::cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) to make some adjustments on the Mat object returned, you must be care about use the gray object image and rgb object, due the

CV_8UC4 is for mRgba
CV_8UC1 is for gray scaled

so I will recomend to check this out.